# What will ES5 code look like for Wordpress CheckboxControl

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, ecmascript-5

I am new to React and Wordpress Gutenberg block. I would like to know what the code below would look like in ES5.

```
    const MyCheckboxControl = () => (
        const [ isChecked, setChecked ] = useState( true );
        <CheckboxControl
            heading="User"
            label="Is author"
            help="Is the user a author or not?"
            checked={ isChecked }
            onChange={ setChecked }
        />
    ) );
```

Comment: It's just a function. Actually it looks wrong, because it doesn't return the JSX.

Comment: It's from Wordpress handbook

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone still uses ES5, you can use `window.wp.element.createElement`:

```
// (function (blocks, element, editor, components) {
// const el = element.createElement
// const { CheckboxControl } = window.wp.components
// ...

el(CheckboxControl, {
  label: "Checkbox Control",
  value: props.attributes.checkboxAttribute,
  onChange: (value) => {
    props.setAttributes({ checkboxAttribute: value })
  }
})

// ...
// })(window.wp.blocks, window.wp.element, window.wp.blockEditor, window.wp.components)
```